# Set default option for `md-radio-group`

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have an extremely simple `md-radio-group` and I am having a tough time setting the default value.  The group is using an object (which I am assuming is related to the problem).

Please reference my [codepen](https://codepen.io/McHolty/pen/XVJEvo) example.

I am defaulting the `md-radio-group` to the 2nd option but the radio button is never selected.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of changes here:

You are interpolating the value of the radio. Doing so is unncessary, and loses reference to the object in the array for which you are iterate. Change your value to `ng-value="option"`.

In your controller, set your default option. Since array positions start at 0, for your second option, you'll use `[1]`.

```
$scope.optionExample = $scope.options[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way if you add another attribute to make default selection, like below

```
$scope.statusList = [{ id: "APN", status: "Approved", isChecked: true }, { id: "VIP", status: "Scheduled", isChecked: false }, ];
```

**in HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-repeat="item in statusList"/>
<label class="form-control" style="width:305px">&#160;{{item.status}} &#160;</label>
```